# How should I restart/retry Kotlin coroutine after exception in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-memory, kotlin-coroutines

I am really happy that I switched my long running tasks, which constantly produce **results to UI thread** to **coroutines**. It improved performance and decreased memory usage by 3 times and all memory leaks disappeared compared to AsyncTask or regular Threads in Android.

The only problem remains is that, I don't know how should I restart my long running operation after exception **has occurred at some time**...

I feel I did not understand exception handling in coroutines at all after reading tons of article. Let me know how can I achieve desired behaviour.

1. I  have coroutine scope in fragment(will move to VM in near future).

​

```
    lateinit var initEngineJob: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = initEngineJob + Dispatchers.Main
```

​

2. Long running task with async/await.

​

```
fun initWorkEngineCoroutine()
    {
        launch {

            while(true) {
                val deferred = async(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    getResultsFromEngine()
                }
                    val result = deferred.await()
                    if (result != null) {
                    //UI thread
                        draw!!.showResult(result)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

fun getResultsFromEngine() :Result? {
           result = // some results from native c++ engine, which throws exception at some times
           return result
   }
```

i don't know where should I put try catch. I tried to surround deferred.await() with try catch, but I could **not call same method in catch block** to retry long running task. I tried *SupervisorJob*(), but no success either. I still could not call **initWorkEngineCoroutine() again** and **start new coroutine**...

Help to solve this issue finally :)

Comment: You never assign anything to `initEngineJob` neither do you use `coroutineContext` - is your sample incomplete?

Comment: I assign initiEngineJob in onCreate. Isn't coroutineContext already overriden, if I use it in Fragment? Android Studio shows that it selects correct coroutineContext

Answer (score 7):

You should treat your code as linear imperative and try/catch where it makes the most logical sense in your code.  With this mindset, your question is probably less about coroutines and more about try/catch retry.  You might do something like so:

```
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        initWorkEngineCoroutine()
    }
}

suspend fun initWorkEngineCoroutine() {
    var failures = 0
    val maxFailures = 3
    while(failures <= maxFailures) {
        try {
             getResultsFromEngine()?.let {
                draw!!.showResult(it)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            failures++
        }
    }
}

// withContext is like async{}.await() except an exception occuring inside 
// withContext can be caught from inside the coroutine.
// here, we are mapping getResultFromEngine() to a call to withContext and 
// passing withContext the lambda which does the work
suspend fun getResultsFromEngine() :Result? = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    Result()
}
```

I've included some logic to prevent infinite loop.  It's probably not going to fit your requirements, but you might consider some sort of thing to prevent an issue where exceptions are raised immediately by `getResultsFromEngine()` and end up causing an infinite loop that could result in unexpected behavior and potential stackoverflow.

Comment: Just one comment, `withContext` is not a shorthand for `async {}.await()` and they differ precisely in exception handling. An exception within `async` that escapes its scope will cause the `async` coroutine to be canceled and propagate the cancellation to the parent coroutine. This will happen whether or not you put `await` inside a `try-catch`. Since `withContext` doesn't create a new coroutine, an exception that escapes it won't cancel anything, it will land in the surrounding `try-catch`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks. i admit i have neglected some additional studying since the move to structured concurrency.  my answer has been updated with what i believe is a more accurate comment on the matter.

Comment: Thanks both of you for clear explanation. I seem to finally get it :) Will try this and will let you (accept answer) shortly